# I cant kill app in android xamarin (Force Stop App)

Tags: android, xamarin

I want force stop my app after activity destroyed , i tried to use

```
 Process.KillProcess(Process.MyPid());
```

the app stop but it still able to force stop it again in Settings>App

I also tried to stop it by this code

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
  am.KillBackgroundProcesses("TurkeyanaCall.TurkeyanaCall");
```

but i got

> An unhandled exception occured.

i want to click this button from my app in anyway

[image]

Comment: This happen in emulator or actual device?

Comment: in the both  emulator and my own phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> Java.Lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: killBackgroundProcesses() from pid=2440, uid=10554 requires android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES

As the [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html) said, `KillBackgroundProcesses`  :

> Have the system immediately kill all background processes associated with the given package. This is the same as the kernel killing those processes to reclaim memory; the system will take care of restarting these processes in the future as needed.
>
> **Requires the KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permission.**

You should add the permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
```

Then you could use it :

```
 ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
 am.KillBackgroundProcesses(PackageName);
 Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(Android.OS.Process.MyPid());
 Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used this to kill all process used in app .

First i stopped all services then i kill the app totally from everywhere the code below explain this .

```
try{
    StopService(new Intent(this, typeof(CallService)));
    StopService(new Intent(this, typeof(TwilioClientService)));
    } catch(Exception ee){ }
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)GetSystemService(Context.ActivityService);
    am.KillBackgroundProcesses("TurkeyanaCall.TurkeyanaCall");
    Android.OS.Process.SendSignal(Android.OS.Process.MyPid(), Signal.Kill);
```